# Delete some html tags just in a few cases with php

Tags: php, html, tags

im using php and i wanna know how to delete `<p class="xxx"></p>` tag

from this:

```
<p class="xxx">
    <a href="xxx" target="xxx">
        <figure>
            <img src="xxx"/>
            <figcaption class="xxx">
                <h1 class="xxx">Text</h1>
                <cite class="xxx">Text</cite>
            </figcaption>
        </figure>
    </a>
</p>
```

to this:

```
<a href="xxx" target="xxx">
    <figure>
        <img src="xxx"/>
        <figcaption class="xxx">
            <h1 class="xxx">Text</h1>
            <cite class="xxx">Text</cite>
        </figcaption>
    </figure>
</a>
```

I wanna delete `<p></p>` just when `<p><a><figure><img/><figcaption><h1></h1><cite></cite></figcaption></figure></a></p>`

i try this:

```
$html = preg_replace("'
(<p[^>]*>)([^<]*<a[^>]*>[^<]*<figure[^>]*>[^<]*<img[^>]*>[^<]*<figcaption[^>]*>[^<]*<h1[^>]*>[^<]*</h1[^>]*>[^<]*<cite[^>]*>[^<]*</cite[^>]*>[^<]*</figcaption>[^<]*[^<]*</figure>[^<]*[^<]*</a>[^<]*)(</p>)'sim", "$2", $valBody);
echo '<H1>Nuevo </H1><br>' . $html;
```

but i cant get it, can you please help me.

Comment: don't use regexes. use [DOM](http://php.net/dom). You will spend FAR more time screaming in frustration and tearing out hair trying to figure out a regex than you will learning DOM, and keep your vocal cords and hairdo intact.

Comment: Obligatory: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags#answer-1732454

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it with [preg_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php), here is how I did it:

```
<?php

$html =<<<HTML
<p class="xxx">
    <a href="xxx" target="xxx">
        <figure>
            <img src="xxx"/>
            <figcaption class="xxx">
                <h1 class="xxx">Text</h1>
                <cite class="xxx">Text</cite>
            </figcaption>
        </figure>
    </a>
</p>
HTML;

$pattern = '#(<p.+">)#';
$replace = '';
$html = preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $html);
$pattern = "#(</p>)#";
$replace = '';
$html = preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $html);
$pattern = "#(\s\s)+#";
$replace = '';
$html = preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $html);

echo '<H1>Nuevo </H1><br>' . $html;

?>
```

This code gives the output as like as it was asked:

```
<H1>Nuevo </H1><br><a href="xxx" target="xxx"><figure><img src="xxx"/><figcaption class="xxx"><h1 class="xxx">Text</h1><cite class="xxx">Text</cite></figcaption></figure></a>
```

I'm a newbie programmer and this is my first answer on Stack Overflow. Best regards.

Comment: its ok but that delete all <p></p> tags, i just wanna delete them when i found this sequence of tags: <p><a><figure><img/><figcaption><h1></h1><cite></cite></figcaption></figure></a></p>

Comment: Oh. Then depending on your situation, you can grab the p element with XPath (if you can know its xpath before) and after that you can do something similar to what I did with preg_replace().